# PdDocument.load() and PdDocument.save() function taking a lot of time

Tags: java, pdfbox

Use case is to remove the bar code from pdf file. Loading a pdf file of size 152mb from file system using pdfbox library

```
pdDocument =PDDocument.load(newFile(aBarcodeVO.getSourceFilePath()),MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
```

and after that removing the bar code and saving the file again on the file system using

```
newDocument.save(aBarcodeVO.getDestinationFilePath(true));
```

The operations such as loading the file and saving the file on file system is taking a lot of time because of which my application is giving gateway timeout error.

While loading and saving the file from file system, it should not take much time.

Comment: `MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly()` makes it slow. But what would you expect with 152 MB? This is quite huge. Get a faster system, allocate more RAM, and make sure you're using the latest version (2.0.27).

Comment: And what is *"a lot of time"* and what is *"not much time"*? How much faster do you need to be?

Comment: @mkl operations such as load and save should be done within 1-2 minutes. Currently it is taking around 5-6 minutes for each operation.

Comment: OK. About a factor 3 is what you want. Have you tried removing the `MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly()` as @Tilman proposed?

Comment: As @TilmanHausherr suggested, removed the `MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly()`. Not had a significant drop in latency when doing `PDDocument.load(newFile(aBarcodeVO.getSourceFilePath()))`. For eg. for a 20mb file, with `MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly()`, loading pdf file took 61sec. In case of without `MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly()`, loading took 56sec.

Comment: 61sec is unusual for a 20MB file. Can you share it?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr cannot share the file for security reasons.

Comment: the pdf file is of 700+pages containing many images, graphics, etc.

Comment: How much time to open https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf ? For me it's 5 seconds.

Comment: @Ayush If you still are interested in this, we'd need an example file to compare and probably optimize loading and saving for. Optimally, it should be a file from your use case. If that's not possible, we can use an arbitrary file, e.g. the one proposed by Tilman. Thus, how much time does Tilman's file take in your setup?

Comment: @mkl thanks a lot for the response, will test it with the file shared by Tilman and will let you know

Comment: Hi @mkl , I am currently working in local testing env, so it is quite slow compared to the qa/live env. Basically, I am doing comparison for the time taken by different files to load and save using pdfbox 2.x library. If talking about the file tilman shared which is approx 21mb, time taken to load is 11.23 min==674 sec whereas on the file which I am trying which is approx 19.5 mb, it is taking 56 sec to load. Also sharing you the file which I am using for testing in my local env: [link](https://cartographicperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/view/cp29-full/pdf).

Comment: Please Note, for this I have used MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly().
Without MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly(), it is taking 618 sec/10.3 min to load  the file provided by tilman and 55 sec for the other file(19.5 mb).

Comment: What we want to achieve is to reduce the time of load() and save() method operations in pdfbox 2.x library, so that in our use case the operations such as loading and saving the file on file system does not take much time in order to avoid gateway timeout error.

Comment: Unfortunately your example site does not appear to react to selecting "download", at least not for me... Nonetheless, if the file @Tilman loads in 5 seconds takes more than 10 minutes in your setup, then this indicates that you need to provide more resources to your code. While his computer may be good, it's surely not technologically ahead of time. On a reasonable computer, therefore, loading that file must not take more than, say, a minute (which would be twelve times slower than Tilman's computer...)

Comment: My computer is several years old 

Comment: thanks for the response @mkl, as mentioned above, I tested in my local env which is quite slow. If tested in qa and live also which is very fast, it is taking time above 5 min for collective operations such as removing and adding qr code image which involves loading and saving the file, hence giving gateway timeout error

Comment: When tried using pdfbox 3.0 alpha, there was a significant drop in latency while loading and saving the file. Can we have a similar fix here in 2.x where these operations take minimum time to execute.

Comment: No, whatever you think happened, happens only in 3.0

Comment: Implementations of loading and saving have been changed considerably in version 3. So, if you want to take advantage of the observed 3.0 loading and saving speeds, you need to wait for the 3.0 release and then switch there.

Comment: @mkl the file can be downloaded from the link by clicking on the "folder arrow down" symbol on the right of the screen. It takes 1 second to open the file on my PC. It has 66 pages.

Comment: Considering those numbers this looks like the code runs with too little resources (CPU or memory) or too slow file access.